What is the difference between .rpc() and .instruction() in anchor test?
I encountered a very strange issue. In the test, when I send an instruction directly using .rpc(), it executes successfully. However, when I use .instruction() and add it to a transaction, my test says it cannot find a certain PDA account. This has been bothering me for a whole day, and it's really strange.
ps : i am using bankrun to test
when i use .rpc(), it will be insufficent cu
        const unstakeAssetIx = await program.methods
          .unstakeAsset()
          .accounts({
            staker: stakerKeypair.publicKey,
            assetA: assetAPublicKey,
            assetB: assetBPublicKey,
          })
          .signers([stakerKeypair])
          .rpc();


but if i add an instruction to increase the cu , it says the PDA account cannot be found.
      const unstakeAssetIx = await program.methods
          .unstakeAsset()
          .accounts({
            staker: stakerKeypair.publicKey,
            assetA: assetAPublicKey,
            assetB: assetBPublicKey,
          })
          .signers([stakerKeypair])
          .instruction();
        const blockhashContext = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

        let unstakeAssetTx = new Transaction({
          blockhash: blockhashContext.blockhash,
          lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashContext.lastValidBlockHeight,
        })
          .add(unstakeAssetIx)
          .add(ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: 230_000 }));

        await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
          connection,
          unstakeAssetTx,
          [stakerKeypair],
          {
            commitment: "confirmed",
          }
        );



I know where the problem occurred. When testing with bankrun, you must use client.processTransaction() to handle the transaction. If you use sendAndConfirmTransaction() to send the transaction, various strange issues will arise!!

The first example (RPC) doesn't have the compute budget program, and I guess your ix burns a lot of CU, so it's running out of CU.
In the second example, one of the accounts you are passing is empty or uninitialized, try to fetch the accounts and check the owner to see which one. My guess is either assetAPublicKey or assetBPublicKey are supposed to be an ATA, and you forgot to do createAssociatedTokenAccount before using them. Or perhaps they are a PDA and you forgot to call init.

My asset A is a Metaplex Core Asset, and I’ve encountered a very strange issue.If it were due to my PDA being incorrect or uninitialized, the first test wouldn’t have executed successfully. However, the first test fails specifically because of insufficient compute units (CU). In contrast, the second test fails because it reports that the PDA account cannot be found. It doesn’t even execute the code within my unstakeAsset instruction.

I don't know why, but as long as I don't use .rpc, the execution fails.
